# Efficient database design- avoiding large number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm building an application that will use a mysql database. In the schema I have a table of data that will be populated externally. In a form similar to this:

```
Item_id |  Name | Value  | Weekoftheyear
```

I then have another table of users for authentication, registration etc.
Another table for department groupings. i.e. A user can belong to a single department. Items can only belong to one user in a department in any week of the year.

The number of items will remain about the same (~700) but the values will change on a week to week basis which will result in a new row in the table above. However, the number of departments/users will continue to increase (depending on the success).

I am trying to figure out the best way to keep track of which user in a group owns which item for every week of the year. I have something like this at the moment:

ID | Weekoftheyear | User | Item

My worry is that this will quickly get too large and become slow to respond. With 700 items and 52 weeks a year. That means 27+ users will mean I go over 1 million rows.

Are there any recommended/ best practices for dealing with something of this kind. I imagine I'm not the first to have this problem and I don't want to re-invent the wheel. Or maybe it just won't be an issue.

Comment: Millions of rows are not a problem. For efficiency, EXPLAIN your queries and make sure your table has appropriate indexes.

Comment: weekoftheyear could be stored as a `DATE` being the first day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't worry about one million rows. That is what databases are for.

With proper indexing, none of your queries will have to rely on more than log(N) jumps. If you keep on mind that indexes are split into disk blocks, which are read in a single operation each, and that there is extensive memory caching of both the indexes and the data, chances are that your queries will never have to access more than 2-3 blocks on disk. That takes an order of milliseconds, so nothing to worry about up-front.

My warmest advice for you is not to worry about performance early on. Just go for the simplest design, and this scheme you have explained has that simplicity feature in it.

Later on, when a year in production passes, and you see actual performance, you might change it. For example, you could split the table horizontally into recent data and historical data. Then tweak the queries to use one or the other or both.

That solution would complicate code and then you will apply it only if you really measure loss of performance. Which, once again, I wouldn't expect with *only* a million of rows.

Answer (score 0):

> My worry is that this will quickly get too large and become slow to respond. With 700 items and 52 weeks a year. That means 27+ users will mean I go over 1 million rows.

Don't worry. Test.

It's trivial to build a table, stuff a million rows in it, and test it. You should be able to do this in your sleep. Think of it as a five-finger exercise for database designers.

A properly designed and indexed table probably won't be slow. I get response times less than 0.2 milliseconds with PostgreSQL on tables of a million rows.

Normalization is your friend. Also note that the week of the year almost certainly needs to include the year.